# I am trying to rename wav files for the correct date format

Tags: r, wav, file-rename, sapply

I need help changing literary thousands of .wav files names like this "2018-10-26 17/11/00" into "2018-10-26 17:11:00" but also subtract 5 hours from that hour of the file, so the final name should be "2018-10-26 12:11:00"
I am using Rstudio in order to do this. What I had before those files were some hexidecimal numbers and the code was:

```
#Convert filenames to date and time of creation
library(tidyverse)

#Set directory to folder containing files
setwd("/Volumes/Informacion/Paisaje Jave/Grabadora 4, (cancha de football)")
#Change this to wherever your files are located
Audiomoth_Dir <- "/Volumes/Informacion/Paisaje Jave/Grabadora 4, (cancha de football)"

#Generate list of files present within the folder
file_list <-list.files(Audiomoth_Dir, pattern = "*.WAV", full.names = FALSE)
#Generate vector of creation dates and times
wav_file_info <- file.info(file_list)
new_names <- as.character(wav_file_info$mtime)
#Rename files
file.rename(from = file_list, to = str_c(new_names,".wav"))
file.rename()
```

Thanks!

After what R2evans told me I made this new code:

```
           file_list <-list.files(Testfolder, pattern = "*.WAV", full.names = FALSE)

           gsub(".wav", "", Testfolder)
           as.POSIXct(gsub(".wav", "", Testfolder), format="%Y-%m-%d %H/%M/%S") - 3600*5

           format(as.POSIXct(gsub(".wav", "", Testfolder), format="%Y-%m-%d %H/%M/%S") - 3600*5,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.wav")

           newTestfolder <- format(as.POSIXct(gsub(".wav", "", Testfolder), format="%Y-%m-%d %H/%M/%S") - 3600*5,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.wav")
           file.rename(from = Testfolder, to=newTestfolder)
```

Comment: Instead of manually subtracting 5 hours from each filename, wouldn't it be better to interpret the actual time in its alleged *timezone*, then output based on a different *timezone*? I'm inferring that's what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: you are absolutely, the thing is that this database is going to be sent to another investigator and it would be wonderful to sent it as the current data instead of the database with the comment that it needs to be interpreted differently. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Though I think one option is to use timezones as applicable, it's also not hard to do this manually:

Some fake filenames, per your description:

```
filenames <- c("2018-10-26 17/11/00.wav", "2018-10-26 03/22/00.wav")
```

The first step is to remove the non-timestamp portion of the name, which in this case should just be the file extension:

```
gsub(".wav", "", filenames)
# [1] "2018-10-26 17/11/00" "2018-10-26 03/22/00"
```

Now if we convert those to `POSIXt` objects and subtract the magic "5 hours":

```
as.POSIXct(gsub(".wav", "", filenames), format="%Y-%m-%d %H/%M/%S") - 3600*5
# [1] "2018-10-26 12:11:00 PDT" "2018-10-25 22:22:00 PDT"
```

we can now use `format` to reintroduce filenames as you intended:

```
newfilenames <- format(as.POSIXct(gsub(".wav", "", filenames), format="%Y-%m-%d %H/%M/%S") - 3600*5,
                       "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.wav")
newfilenames
# [1] "2018-10-26 12:11:00.wav" "2018-10-25 22:22:00.wav"
```

Then you can simply rename them as `file.rename(filenames, newfilenames)`.

Comment: Thank you, I definitely would do it manually, the real problem is that this database is going to be sent to another investigator.

Comment: When I say "manually", I mean hard-coding `3600*5`, not manually typing in `mv oldname newname` in a terminal. See my edit for the final step.

Comment: I am sorry R2evans, I am pretty new at this, so I didn´t understood you quite good, this is the code that I have but it didn´t worked. I made a new folder for tests...

Comment: You say it doesn't work but that doesn't help me help you at all. Error messages? Warnings?

Comment: I made an edit on the principal message, there is the codes I placed. The error was: file.rename(from = Testfolder, to=newTestfolder)
[1] FALSE

Comment: All that indicates is that the renaming was unsuccessful, but it could be due to a number of factors: file not found and permissions are the first two that come to mind. What does `system(paste("mv", dQuote(filenames[1]), dQuote(newfilenames[1]))` return?